# Cannot raise custom exception in Rails 5.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, exception

I am developing a RoR application. I need to use a custom exception I implemented. It looks like this:

```
# app/exceptions/JobError.rb
module Exceptions
   class JobError < StandardError
      # ... 
   end
end
```

However, I got a `uninitialized constant JobError` when I raise the exception. I tried different namespaces but none of them work:

```
raise JobError.new()
raise Exceptions::JobError.new()
raise ::Exceptions::JobError.new()
```

Any idea?

Comment: According to the documentation, all subdirectories of app in the application and engines present at boot time. For example, app/controllers. They do not need to be the default ones, any custom directories like app/workers belong automatically to autoload_paths. So in my case, my module is autoloaded. So I should be able to use the exception

Answer (score 2):

My bad, I wrote the file name in CamelCase, not in snake_case...

Comment: I guess you mean \*snake_case